# IntraWeb page with ribbonbar

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ribbon, intraweb

We have VCL applications that use the DevExpress TdxRibbon or XE2 TRibbon components, with one being written using the MVP design pattern.

We now want to create a web version of that app, so I'm looking for IntraWeb components that can reproduce a similiar ribbon bar.

There wasn't a suitable component in the TMS Software IntraWeb Component Pack, and DevExpress don't make web versions of their controls. A Google search didn't locate anything suitable in the first 10 pages of results I looked at.

Does anyone know of a Intraweb component that can produce the effect I'm after, or do I need to script it directly into the page?